# Pesquisar em um campo com codificação JSON

Tags: mysql, sql

Existe um campo na tabela em que o conteúdo antes de ser gravado é codificado em JSON.

O conteúdo é gravado da seguinte forma:

```
[["nome_completo","Ana Concei\u00e7\u00e3o Dias"],["idade","27 anos"],["cidade","Lisboa"]]
```

No PhpMyAdmin, o select abaixo não retorna nenhum resultado:

```
SELECT * 
FROM funcionarios
WHERE custom LIKE '%Ana Concei\u00e7\u00e3o Dias%'
```

Como fazer a consulta acima retornar o respectivo registo?

Comment: Qual é o banco que você está usando? Fiz um teste aqui no MySQL e no SQL Server 2008 e ambos retornaram o resultado certo.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro estou usando MySQL.

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta o código PHP que você está usando. Pode ser alguma coisa lá.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro estou utilizando o phpmyadmin retirei a tag PHP para não gerar confusão.

Comment: Tente `WHERE custom LIKE '%Ana Conceição Dias%'`

Comment: @bfavaretto tentei assim também e não funcionou.

Comment: Tente então escapando cada barra: \\

Comment: @bfavaretto consegui, mas utilizando 4 barras. "Ana Concei\\\\u00e7\\\\u00e3o Dias".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução aqui:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Como o MySQL usa sintaxe de escape do C em strings ( por exemplo, "\n" para representar uma nova linha ), é necessário dobrar qualquer "\".

Por exemplo, para procurar "\n" , é necessário especificar "\n". Para procurar "\", especifique-o como "\\" ; isso é porque as barras invertidas são eliminadas uma vez pelo analisador e novamente quando a correspondência de padrões é feita , deixando uma única barra invertida a ser procurada.

A query ficou da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT *  
FROM funcionarios
WHERE custom LIKE '%Ana Concei\\\\u00e7\\\\u00e3o Dias%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Meu código abaixo não é uma solução completa, copy/paste não vai funcionar. Destina-se a empurrá-lo na direção certa. Suponho que o meu código pode ter alguns erros, embora eu não estou vendo isso. Se alguém encontrar o erro, por favor, `DEIXE UM COMENTÁRIO.`

Primeiro queria saber porque você converteu os resultados para Json antes de salvar no banco. Você já tem uma matriz, você não precisa de uma string JSON no seu caso. Você precisa converter de volta com isso:

```
$yourArray = json_decode($json)
```

Agora você pode inserir os dados na tabela. Eu não sei como está seu insert , mas se eu olhar para o seu código, eu acho que o seu sql seria algo parecido com isto:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela(id, nome_completo, idade, cidade) VALUES (:id, :nome_completo, :idade, :cidade)';
```

Portanto, o seu código seria algo parecido com isto:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela(id, nome_completo, idade, cidade) VALUES (:id, :nome_completo, :idade, :cidade)';
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $yourArray ['id']);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome_completo', $yourArray['nome_completo']);
...
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
```

**Esta é a forma correta de armazenar seus dados "Json", assim você poderá fazer select sem problemas.**

Comment: Rafael, eu agradeço a ajuda mas o problema não é sobre como gravar os dados e sim como pesquisar em um campo que foi gravado com codificação JSON. Eu não disse que construi o sistema assim, apenas estou tentando no MySql fazer uma consulta em uma tabela que tem o campo codificado. O sistema não é meu mas se fosse faria como você fez, campos separados e utilizaria prepared statements.

Comment: Claro que a minha reposta não é sobre um problema de gravação de dados, mas sim sobre UM PROBLEMA QUE FOI CRIADO GRAVANDO DA FORMA PERGUNTADA. Então apontei-lhe uma solução "cabível". Boa sorte!